# Autocomplete multiple fields with jquery in Rails 5

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete

I am building an admin form where I am using Jquery's Autocomplete widget for one of the text fields.

In a field called *customer_phone_number*, when someone types the phone number, autocomplete checks the database to see if it exists and lists the existing options. Once a phone number is selected, I want it to fill out another field called *customer_name*. I've managed to autocomplete the first one but not the other. Here's what my code looks like right now:

This is the View:

```
<div class="col-md-4 input">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Customer's Phone Number</label>
    <%= f.text_field :customer_phone_number, class: "form-control", data: { autocomplete_source: customers_path }  %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 input">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Customer's Name</label>
    <%= f.text_field :customer_name, class: "form-control", data: { autocomplete_source: customers_path }  %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The javascript file:

```
jQuery(function() {

  return $('#customer_phone_number').autocomplete({
    source: $('#customer_phone_number').data('autocomplete-source'),
    select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault(),
      $(this).val(ui.item.phone_number),
      $('#customer_name').val(ui.item.name);
    }
  });
});
```

And Controller:

```
  def index
    @customer = Customer.order(:phone_number).where("phone_number like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%").limit(5)
    render json: @customer.map{ |customer| { :phone_number => customer.phone_number, :name => customer.name } }
    # render json: @customer.pluck(:phone_number, :name)

  end
```

How can I pass the *:name* value to the *customer_name* field?

Comment: It should work with your code. Check whether the id attribute of `customer_name` `text_field` is `customer_name` or not.

Comment: It is, but the autocomplete list still seems to be empty. Do you have any idea of what else may be going wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Johnny A bit confusion with your code is the field name `customer_phone_number` or `phone_number` in `Customer` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to make it work using a different method with the rails-jquery-autocomplete gem:

https://github.com/risuiowa/rails-jquery-autocomplete/

Using the

> autocomplete_field

turned out to be much easier to implement.
Example:

```
form_for @product do |f|
  f.autocomplete_field :brand_name, autocomplete_brand_name_products_path
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are fetching wrong query as in form field name is `customer_phone_number` and in query its `phone_number`

Assuming in `Customer` model field name is `customer_phone_number` then query should be

```
def index
    @customer = Customer.order(:customer_phone_number).where("customer_phone_number like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%").limit(5)
    render json: @customer.map{ |customer| { :phone_number => customer.customer_phone_number, :name => customer.name } }

end
```

Comment: In the Customer model, the field name is phone_number.

Comment: @Johnny If its so then why are you using `customer_phone_number` in `form_for`?

Comment: No particular reason. That's just how I'm referencing it in another model, because I thought it would make it confusing to not have customer_, especially for the _name field. Wouldn't it?

Comment: ok, so Can you run your query at rails console `customer = Customer.order(:phone_number).where("phone_number like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%").limit(5)` replace `params[:term]` with your `query param` and do you get any record there?

Comment: No, it's not returning anything. The way I've managed to make it work with one attribute was by using pluck:

render json: @owner.pluck(:phone_number)

When I try something similar with map, it doesn't work though.

Comment: @Johnny `Customer.order(:phone_number).where("phone_number like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")` is it's not returning anything that is returns a blank array so you are not getting anything any autocomplete elements with that `params[:term]`, make sure you have some records with that `params[:term]` .

Comment: I may be not passing the right command to the console. 

If I go to "localhost:3000/customers", it does show an array with five records. That makes me think that the array is being passed through by the Controller.  No data is displayed in the autocomplete list though. So, is there any chance that autocomplete is not interpreting the array properly?